# Is there an Angular2 router url syntax standard?

Tags: url, angular, url-routing, angular2-routing

I'm using Angular 2 and Typescript 2.

I'm currently reading about and experimenting with the Router in Angular 2.

In Victor Savkin's Router book he refers to url's like these:

```
/inbox/33(popup:compose)
```

and

```
/inbox/33;open=true/messages/44
```

My questions is "Is there some standard that documents this URL syntax in a formal manner?"

Like usage of the parentheses and colon and semi-colon...?

I've looked around and can't seem to find anything like this.  I know MVC routing using C# has a similar feel, but it seems like these things are turning into the wild west as far as being formalized and documented.

Comment: Right now documentation on Angular 2 is evolving hence there is no proper documentation about auxilary routes, Victor Savkin's Router book is best bet right now with lot of examples and insight :)

Answer (score 1):

I do in the app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: 'example/:id', component: ExampleComponent }])
```

Comment: Imagine you want to match everything. Use { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

Comment: And now imagine you want to get back your param in your ngOnInit method. Do something like _this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];_